# How to replicate header behavior of Google Chrome Android App

Tags: android

The Google Chrome Android app has some interesting header behavior. If you open a tab, do a search, and then start to scroll down, the header containing your search will disappear. You can scroll to all the way down the page, and then as soon as you start to scroll back up the header is the first thing that scrolls back into view, and then further scrolling will scroll you back up the page.

I'm sure there is a library or something somewhere that replicates this, or there is a way to implement this.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I've been searching for this for ~30 minutes. It's difficult to put into words.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This pattern is called a 'Quick Return Bar', as described in [Roman Nurk's Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) and implemented in [this code](https://gist.github.com/imminent/4576886).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Follow up question about the source though. Any idea why there is a <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/empty" that isn't used in the source?

Comment: @spierce7 - from [ListFragment's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html): "Optionally, your view hierarchy can contain another view object of any type to display when the list view is empty. This "empty list" notifier must have an id "android:empty". Note that when an empty view is present, the list view will be hidden when there is no data to display."

An empty `FrameLayout` just means that the list will not be shown when there is no data. You could certainly replace it with a `TextView` saying 'No data' or whatever is appropriate for your app

Comment: @ianhanniballake I really need help with I'm trying to use the above code for the view which is on the top but not able to achieve the hiding and showing